# Spring Controller URL Mapping issues

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following URL mapping in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/additem.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/additem/fileupload.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

I click on page with  `href="additem.htm"` and it goes to the controller with `value="/additem.htm"` above. I fill up form in that and submit the form.

The form gets posted to `action="additem/fileupload.htm"`, which goes to the controller with `value="/additem/fileupload.htm"`. Once i complete this fileupload controller and returns a jsp the browser urls turns to `"http://localhost:8080/Dream/additem/fileupload.htm"`.

The problem is, when I again click on the first link with `href="additem.htm"`, it is trying to search for controller with mapping like `"additem/additem.htm"`.

Even when i hover over the link the browser is showing the url as `http://localhost:8080/Dream/additem/additem.htm` and it throws an error. How do i resolve this URL issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a link in a jsp, use the c:url tag to generate urls relative to your app's context path:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<a href="<c:url value="/additem.htm" />">Click here</a>
```

It will prepend your application's context path to the href. It should generate:

```
<a href="/Dream/additem.htm">Click here</a>
```

Comment: and take note of the leading slash in the value of the c:url.  Without that, it'll be relative and you'll end up with just what you have now.