# Path to JQuery library in <script> tag using Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc

I downloaded jquery library and added it to WebContent/js folder in Spring MVC project. In my jsp file i have a line
 but when i try to use jquery functions, it doesnt work. When i replace source path to "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" it works fine. Jsp files are located in "WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp" folder. What is the correct path to jquery library?

Comment: So you have a bad path to that folder. what is the question?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090035/spring-controller-url-mapping-issues/9091075#9091075). Basically you need to use the `<c:url />` tag to generate the correct relative path to your script.

In your case, you'll want to use:

```
<script src="<c:url value='/js/jquery.js' />"></script>
```